# where are the pictures of the skype contacts saved (see if someone is invisible)

Tags: macos, mac, contacts, skype

i just thought you could see if someone is invisible in skype, if you just delete (reset) his profile picture. Because i know if you install skype on a new device the profile pictures are saved only if he is online (or invisible). That means if i just want to so if someone is invisible you just delete or reset his profile picture and if you see after a few seconds his picture again = he is invisible.

BUT...
i don't know where the contact picture are saved on on my mac (running mountain lion). I just couldn't find theme...
so if you know where they are saved, would it be great.

Comment: Skype's files are stored in ~/Library/Application Support/Skype but there are no icon visible. They are probably embedded in a binary file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Skype 6.3.xx the avatars are stored in

```
~/Library/Caches/com.skype.skype/(your skype name)/SKAvatarCache
```

in TIFF format. You can view them by in Preview by opening Terminal and running

```
open ~/Library/Caches/com.skype.skype/(your skype name)/SKAvatarCache/(name of the file)
```

Comment: What version of Skype are you running? Looks like the first path I found are leftovers from an old version of Skype, but I'm not sure how old.

Comment: Skype version 6.3.0.582

Answer (score 0):

The avatars are cached in `~/Library/Application Support/Skype/AvatarCache`.

To access this, open a Finder window, hit Cmd+Shift+G to bring up the "Go To" dialog, copy and paste that path in to the dialog and hit enter. You'll see a directory full of `.jpeg` images -- those are the avatar images for your contacts.

Edit: Buscar's answer is correct. These appear to be left over from a very old version of Skype.

Comment: thx for the fast answer but i couldn't finde a file called AvatarCach  i only have files like my username and other files but no AvatarCach

Comment: It's a directory. And make sure you spell it correctly. ;)

Comment: i did exactly what you said but than it says "The Folder can't be found" (i don't know if it is important but i am running mountain lion)

Comment: I do not have that AvatarCache on my MBA 10.8